# contour integral of airy function to real integral

Tags: complex-analysis

The Airy function is written as: Ai(z) = $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{v_k} e^{-i(\frac{u^3}{3}+zu)} du$ where ${v_k}$ is two line segment, first: from $u=ke^{\frac{-5\pi}{6}}$ to u=0, second: u=0 to $u=ke^{\frac{-\pi}{6}}$, however the airy function is also equivalent to the following through limiting procedure $\lim_{k\to\infty}$:   Ai(z) = $\frac{1}{2\pi}$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{(-\mathrm{i}tz-\frac{it^3}{3})} \mathrm{dt}$. I would like to show how this is true . I've tired to deform the line segment to vertical and horizontal contour, but no avail.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: is that better?

Comment: It is better, yes.

Comment: Are you aware of the methods described in [this document](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0506158.pdf) ?